# Logging xm console output in xen?

Tags: logging, console, xen

Is there a way I can log the output of xm console in to some file?

Can I set something in the domain configuration file which automatically does this for me when I issue xm create?

I tried:

```
xm console | tee domU-console.log
```

... , but that does not fit in my case. I want to log the output asynchronously in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that works then you ought to be able to :

```
nohup xm console | tee domU-console.log &
```

I don't know if `xm console` uses stderr at all but if you want to be sure to snag tht output, too, do this:

```
nohup xm console 2>&1 tee domU-console.log &
```

Drop the `tee` if you intend on logging out.

Answer (score 3):

Your can try *xenconsoled* like

> xenconsoled --log=guest --log-dir=/var/log/xen/guest/

And Redhat also save guest console output to /var/log/xen/console, if you set /etc/sysconfig/xend with XENCONSOLED_LOG_GUESTS=yes.

Comment: And on Debian, putting `XENCONSOLED_ARGS="--log=guest --log-dir=/var/log/xen/guest/"` into _/etc/default/xend_ works.

Answer (score 0):

Procedure 1: Access to Console of Single Guest VM

1: Open XenCenter, go to General tab of the VM which you want access, and check for the UUID

2: Open XenServer text console, run the list_domains command, and find the VM UUID in the output

3: Run the following command to access guest VM console:

/usr/lib/xen/bin/xenconsole < domain id >

Procedure 2: Log Output of Newly Created Linux VMs to Text File

To collect and save output from all VMs running on the XenServer host, complete the following procedure:

1: Run the following command on XenServer host:

xenstore-write /local/logconsole/@ /tmp/console.%d.log

2: Restart the VM from which you want to collect the console output.

3: Verify if file /tmp/console..log exists. This file should contain VM console output. To find domain ID, refer to Procedure 1: Access to Console of Single Guest VM.

4: Run the following command to stop logging console output:

xenstore-rm /local/logconsole/@

https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX137216